# Exception in json.decode : Closure: () => String from Function 'toString'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting some data from API in flutter. I am trying to decode the data using `json.decode()` but this decode function gives me the following error:

`Closure: () => String from Function 'toString'`

Here's my code:

```
Future<Product> createOrder() async {
    var client = new http.Client();
    var productModel = null;

    try {
      var response = await client
          .get(Uri.https('butterbasket.onrender.com', Strings.createOrderUrl));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = response.body;
        print("Body: $body");
        var jsonMap = json.decode(body);
        var productModel = Product.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception: ${e.toString}");
    }
    return productModel;
  }
```

Here is the Error Debug Console:
[image: Debug Console]

Comment: `body` is already a `String`, you don't need to use `.toString()` on it again

Comment: Still no good. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into issues because the data you are loading in is an array, but the model is an object. You'll need to do something like the following:

```dart
final List jsonProducts = json.decode(body)
final List<Product> products = 
     jsonProducts.map((jsonProduct) => Product.fromJson(jsonProduct)).toList();
```

and then if you only need the first item you can do:

```
final Product product = products[0]
```

But don't forget to check if the array is big enough.

Comment: BTW, The "error" you are getting is probably related to how you are trying to print the error. try just calling `print(e)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your Future function must return an optional **Product?**, otherwise your future will never find a result as you are declaring it inside the function.

Instead of:

```
Future<Product> createOrder() async {}
```

Use:

```
Future<Product?> createOrder() async {}
```

Finally your async snapshot and FutureBuilder type should be of type **<Product?>**.